# How to identify if one is enlightened or not? and what is enlightenment?

Tags: enlightenment

Very often we see most of the Anandas claiming "i'm enlightened", Now we have Doctor (MBBS degree holder) similarly how common people know about a person is enlightened or charlatan? If you are enlightened in one philosophy like Advaita, Are they qualified to be called themselves as God? Ask people to worship themselves.. God as we know he should not age, afflicted with illness, defying death. Not slayed but hiraynakashipu and ravana would have passed all the said with 100% score if you have the 3 tests. so what determines enlightenment..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91713/discussion-on-question-by-prasanna-r-how-to-identify-if-one-is-enlightened-or-no).

Comment: i think its duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Mudakopanishad says -"Brahmavid Brahmaiva Bhavathi" One who knows Brahman is Brahman.
But who knows it completely or correctly?

"Aham Nirvikalpo Niraakaara Rupo, Vibhutvaaccha Sarvatra Sarvendriyaanaam
Na Chaa Sangatan Naiva Muktir Na meyah Chidananda Rupah Shivoham Shivoham"        says Nirvanashtakam.
It means:-
" I am all pervasive. I am without any attributes and without any form. I have neither attachment to the world, nor to liberation. I have no wishes for anything because I am everything, everywhere, every time, always in equilibrium. I am indeed, That eternal knowing and bliss, Shiva, love and pure consciousness."

So, one who has absolutely no desires and has gone beyond the name and form illusion and is one with all accepting all as Self, always in equilibrium can be called as an enlightened being.

Truly speaking there is no second to Self. But we forget this fact in the dream of life. The one who has fixed his mind on TATH and will never be deluded again by this dream of duality is realized, soul. Fried seeds don't germinate. Similarly, the one who has burnt his desires by the flame of self enquiry will never be deluded. Ashtavakra Geetha by Chinmayananda speaks beautifully about this.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, enlightenment does not technically mandate a Guru. However, just like studying a Chess game by a Grandmaster  helps avoid common pitfalls, studying a path that a truly enlightened one took would help and sure does. 
Ask these questions to a supposed Guru.you will know the fake ones. This is assuming your values are as appropriate for enlightenment....

1) Why Death the fifth?

2) What is standing behind the veil mean? Why should the enlightened ones do it?

3) Why does Shiva cry on a Cremation ground?

4) Tavad akasamkalpo yavacchabdah pravartate ,

And no they are not qualified to be called as God