# What is the experience after or during enlightenment?

Tags: enlightenment

I am very eager to know about the experience during and after enlightenment.

- Can anyone please help me to answer this question?
- Do people see a huge amount of light or see God in a 'Shakara' form?

I don't know much about this, please correct me in case the question is not correct enough to be answered.

Comment: It is like asking about feeling after having a sumptuous meal. :-).  No one can explain in words. It can only be experienced

Comment: [Similar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34068/3869) question was asked earlier.

Comment: how to explain the taste of ghee to someone who has never tasted? What is the difference in seeing a map of Mumbai and seeing/experiencing Mumbai? The experience is beyond explanation. It is why the Upanishads say only neti, neti - not this, not this.